# kivy python List to button text

Tags: python, kivy

Trying to populate the text of three buttons with the content of myList["One", "Two", "Three"]
btn1 = myList[1] etc

myList will be populated fron csv file

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
    BoxLayout:

    Button:
        id: btn1
    Button:
        id: btn2
    Button:
        id: btn3
"""


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        my_box = Builder.load_string(kv)
        my_ShowList = ['My Way', 'Wine Drinker', 'Boots']

        '''
        This is where I get lost
        want to use for loop to populate Button text with my_ShowList items
        '''


        return my_box


if __name__ == '__main__':

    TestApp().run()enter code here`
```

Comment: Could you give more details? Show some code?

Comment: added code as best I can new to this first post be gentle

Comment: You definitely should format your code. For more info visit [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: I wanted to use kv file for kv builder string to keep Layout separate and to use kv features where possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it entirely in python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestClass(App):
    def build(self):
        my_box = BoxLayout()
        my_show_list = ["My Way", "Wine Drinker", "Boots"]
        my_box.my_buttons = [] # if you want to keep an "easy" reference to your buttons to do something with them later
                               #kivy doesnt crashes because it creates the property automatically
        for message in my_show_list:
            button = Button(text=message)
            my_box.my_buttons.append(button)
            my_box.add_widget(button)
        return my_box


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestClass().run()
```

Comment: Adding some explanations for OP would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve this problem:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn_list = ['My Way', 'Wine Drinker', 'Boots']
        for btn_text in self.btn_list:
            self.add_widget(Button(text=btn_text))


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```